# Can you view a list of captured Boos?

Tags: luigis-mansion-3

Is there anyway to view a list of Boos you've already captured on a Luigi's Mansion 3 save file?

There doesn't seem to be anything in the gallery - although I can see regular ghosts and the gem list.

I haven't played my save file in a while, and I know I captured some Boos, but I can't remember on which floors. I want to go search the floors I haven't found the Boo yet, and not waste time on the floors I have. But I don't see a simple way to figure out which floors still have a Boo.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can definitely see captured Boos from your gallery, here's the proof:

From the Ghost page, use the *left stick* to change page: moving up or down you can see Regular ghosts, Rare ghosts, Boss ghosts and Boos.

It's easy to know which floor you missed since there's a Boo for each floor.

If you need a quick check, here's the [list of Boos for every floor](https://www.nintendolife.com/guides/luigis-mansion-3-how-to-catch-boos-and-where-to-find-them):

- Floor B1: Basement – Boosement
- Floor 1: Grand Lobby – Gumboo
- Floor 2: Mezzanine – Booigi
- Floor 3: Hotel Shops – Kungboo
- Floor 4: The Great Stage – Boogie
- Floor 5: RIP Suites – Booldog
- Floor 6: Castle MacFrights – Boo-at-Arms
- Floor 7: Garden Suites – Bootanist
- Floor 8: Paranormal Productions – Booducer
- Floor 9: Unnatural History Museum – Boones
- Floor B2: Boilerworks – Combooster
- Floor 10: Tomb Suites – Anuboo
- Floor 11: Twisted Suites – Boofuddler
- Floor 12: The Spectral Catch – Boocaneer
- Floor 13: Fitness Center – Boodybuilder
- Floor 14: The Dance Hall – Boosician

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thanks!

Comment: @Tronman you're welcome! But those menus are actually more complicated and less intuitive than needed.